# Make entire <li> clickable with <a> element inside without javascript

Tags: html, css

Is there any way?

I have a `<ul>` with some `<li>` elements inside. It's part of a dropdown menu. Each `<li>` becomes a box the size of the largest `<li>` element in the group (the one with the most text inside it).

The problem is I want people to be able to click anywhere inside each `<li>` box and have the link work, instead of just where the text is. I would like a non javascript solution if possible.

Here's some sample HTML. The inner `<li>` elements are the ones with the links.

```
<li class="parent Glass" style=" float: left;">

Glass
    <ul class="child" style="float: left; position: absolute; z-index: 999; display: none;">
    <li style=" float: left;">
                <a href="http://example.com/path/to/somehwere.html?glass=25">Brown       (13)</a>

    </li>
    <li style=" float: left;">
                <a href="http://example.com/path/to/somehwere.html?glass=112">Crystal       (93)</a>

    </li>
    <li style=" float: left;">
                <a href="http://example.com/path/to/somehwere.html?glass=99">Gray       (1)</a>

    </li>
    <li style=" float: left;">
                <a href="http://example.com/path/to/somehwere.html?glass=42">Latte       (12)</a>

    </li>
    <li style=" float: left;">
                <a href="http://example.com/path/to/somehwere.html?glass=72">White       (15)</a>

    </li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: Try `a {display: block}`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to add `display:block` to your `<a>` tags, then you can set a width and height or padding [on the `<a>`], if you want to make the clickable region bigger.

Comment: How do I make the clickable region fill the parent element without knowing exactly how big the parent element will be?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: block-level elements naturally fill the width of their parent. They won't fill the height though. That's why I like to set the sizing properties on the `<a>` and just let the `li` "collapse" so its tight around the "a" by setting `padding:0` on the `li`.

Comment: Couldn't you just make a div per item and make the div itself clickable?

Comment: @Paul How are you going to make a div clickable without JavaScript?