# How do I put a tags around the <li> tags in my wordpress navigation?

Tags: wordpress, list, hyperlink, navigation

I'm new to making wordpress templates and stumbled upon a problem, where you'll most likely have to edit something within the wordpress defaults.

I use the command wp_list_pages to show all pages. This works fine, but the output looks like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="#">Page Name</a></li>
```

I'd like to have the a tag to wrap the <li> tag, so that the whole styled <li> area is clickable and not only the text. Do you have an idea how to make this happen?
Also, other solutions to make the whole <li> area clickable would be welcome as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping an `<li>` within an `<a>` is invalid HTML.  There is really no good reason to do this.  You can use CSS to achieve what you want without mangling the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I would say: **don't**.

Wrapping a `<li>` tag is invalid HTML (try passing it into http://validator.w3.org/check).

Instead, I would recommend styling the `<li>` tag itself such that it becomes clickable via the `page_item` css class. You shouldn't need to wrap the tag itself just for that.

Basic example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxpPD/)

Answer (score 0):

*Correction regarding semantic comment props to @Sparky

This would generate invalid HTML (rather than being a semantic issue)

What you might want to do is set the CSS for the a to `display: block;`

[How do I make the whole area of a list item in my navigation bar, clickable as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074454/how-do-i-make-the-whole-area-of-a-list-item-in-my-navigation-bar-clickable-as-a)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14803036/2821387

Comment: "Semantics" is beside the point... _it's just plain invalid HTML_.

Comment: I take your point and note you also commented above. Corrected.